# how to make a thread(feeder) to add certain amount of task in a queue then wait until second thread(consumer) do its work

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multiprocessing

I'm using multithreading to run two thread A and B in parallel one is acting as a feeder to the queue `collections.deque` and second thread `B` is working as a consumer and they are working fine,

**problem**

Now I am trying to run thread `A` (feeder) to run and add certain amount of tasks to queue say limit is 5, when it reaches the limit it should wait then thread `B` (consumer) start processing until the queue is empty and once the queue is empty thread `A` starts again and this loop carry on.

**My question is**

how can achieve this?
multithreading is needed or not and if not what is the best way.
how can I add a limit to a queue?

Note: this program will keep on ruining in background.

Comment: This question seems quite broad. There are numerous tutorials online with the exact topic of the consumer/producer problem in python, including [this one](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2013/10/producer-consumer-problem-in-python/). Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @infobiac thank for attachment it was helpful, specifically i want thread A (feeder) to add 5 task  to a queue and then wait until thread B (consumer) complete consumed that tasks.then thread A should start  and thread B should wait() until there are 5 tasks in queue